# Python generate tets image file in memory

Tags: python, django

i have been trying a few solutions that i found here but non of the is able to pass validation by  https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/imghdr.html IMGHDR built-in python module via `imghdr.what()` method.

Question is - is it possible generate in-memory image file in a such a way that it would pass validation by `imghdr.what()`???

Needed for Django tests.

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to look into a ramdisk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a (dummy) image to memory and read it from there using BytesIO:

```
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
import imghdr

def dummyImage(imgFormat):
    storage = BytesIO()
    img = Image.new("RGB", (640, 480))
    img.save(storage, imgFormat)

    storage.seek(0)  # important for imghdr to read from the beginning! 
    imgType = imghdr.what('test', h=storage.read())  # what() needs a dummy filename!
    return imgType


for imgFormat in ('PNG', 'BMP', 'JPEG'):
    print(dummyImage(imgFormat))
```

Ouput:

```
png
bmp
jpeg
```